# Setting a number in range in arrays for java

Tags: java, arrays, range

While writing a code for printing out random numbers ranging from 0 to 99, I had faced some difficulties. I tried to change the condition in the for statement to e<100, however, it had occurred an error. Where should I put the conditions in order for my output to show numbers between 0 to 99?

```
public class EvensOdds {

public static void printArray(int[] ear) {
    
    System.out.println("ODD NUMBERS : ");
    for (int e = 0; e<ear.length ; e ++) {
        ear[e] = (int)(Math.random()* 10);
            if(ear[e]%2!=0)
            System.out.print(ear[e] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println("\n" + "EVEN NUMBERS : ");
    for (int e = 0; e<ear.length ; e ++) {
        ear[e] = (int)(Math.random()* 10);
            if(ear[e]%2==0)
            System.out.print(ear[e] + "  ");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numberArray = new int[25];
    printArray(numberArray);

}

}
```

Comment: `Math.random()` Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.  By multiplying by 10 you cover the range [0,10). To extend it to the range [0,100) multiply it by 100.

Comment: Please look at  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java

Comment: Why are you using an array?  Especially considering you are overwriting it with the even numbers.  Just use a simple int variable and pass the desired count to the method.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8, below creates an array with size 25, with random entries between 0,99

```
    Random random = new Random();
    int[] array = random.ints(25, 0, 100).toArray();
```

Comment: You should correct your answer and change 99 to 100 as the OP wanted to include 99.  The way you wrote it only numbers `0 <= x <= 98` will be considered.